# Erro durante a desserialização do corpo da mensagem de resposta para a operação - WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl

Sou novo em implementar servicos como referência, e me vejo no momento num beco sem saída.

Consigo testar a chamada ao serviço com sucesso via Postman. 
Vale dizer que um certificado é requerido, mas uma vez adicionado no Postman, não tenho nenhum problema.

Estou tentando consumir este mesmo serviço referenciado em minha aplicação em Web_AppReferences. 
O arquivo .wsdl usado para adicionar a referência ao projeto provém de uma url fornecida pela empresa que o desenvolveu.
Dessa forma, como é de se esperar, algumas classes (tipos) são geradas e disponibilizadas como metadados.
Entre elas temos a classe (tipo) que me permite instanciar o cliente que consumirá o serviço e a classe (tipo) que será usado para receber a resposta.

O objeto cliente usado para fazer a chamada ao serviço precisa ser configurado em minha aplicação para cumprir os requisitos do serviço:

```
var transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
transport.RequireClientCertificate = true;  
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(new CustomTextMessageBindingElement("ISO-8859-1", "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11), transport);       
cliente.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
cliente.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = SecureWebServiceHelper.CriarCertificado();
```

A seguir, o cliente chama o servico passando o parâmetro esperado:

```
respostasolicitarProtocoloWS resposta = cliente.solicitarProtocoloOperation(solicitacao);
```

Contudo, ao obter a resposta do mesmo, uma exception é gerada:

*"Exeption: Erro durante a desserialização do corpo da mensagem de resposta para a operação 'solicitarProtocoloOperation'.
InnerException: Erro no documento XML (1, 548).
InnerException: Caractere inválido na codificação fornecida. Linha 1, posição 548."*

Consultando a empresa que me disponibiliza o serviço, recebo a informação de que minhas chamadas ocorrem com sucesso dentro da aplicação deles.
Isto me leva a pensar que o problema possa ser gerado por alguma configuração errada em minha aplicação ou mesmo no Visual Studio.
Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Tente modificar as seguintes configurações no app.config do cliente:

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```